# Filtering models from a Backbone Collection and then setting attributes for those models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

`this.model.collection.where({selected: true})` returns an array of models

I want to then set the `selected` attribute of the returned models to false.

How can I do this?

`@model.collection.where({selected: true})` (coffeescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with a simple loop?

```
m.set('selected', false) for m in @model.collection.where(selected: true)
```

or even:

```
for m in @model.collection.where(selected: true)
    m.set('selected', false)
```

Underscore is nice but that doesn't mean that you have to use it for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `.each`

```
_.each(this.model.collection.where({selected: true}), function(m){
    m.set('selected', false);
});
```

Since [`where` returns an array of matching objects](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-where), you have to pass that array into the first argument for underscore's `each`.

You could also do this with `map`:

```
this.model.collection.map(function(m){if(m.get('selected'){m.set('selected', false);}});
```

Since `map` takes every element in a collection (or array) and applies a method to them.

Comment: I really like these solutions, I went with @mu_is_too_short's answer because it seemed more readable in coffeescript. Thank you for taking the time help out!

Answer (score -1):

```
this.model.collection.where({selected: true}).each(function(model){
    model.set({selected:false});
}
```